# Checking to see if getAccountsByType() found an account

Tags: java, android, accountmanager

I am working on implementing a custom account type for AccountManager. I am looking for an account with the following code:

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this); 
Account[] accounts = am.getAccountsByType("com.mycustomtype");
```

I'm new to this and don't know how to process the result. I basically want an if statement that sets a variable to 0 if no account is found, and otherwise sets a username variable. This way I know whether to start a loginActivity or my mainActivity.

How do I process the result of AccountManager in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this working using array.length as follows:

```
private boolean accountExists = false;

    AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this); 
Account[] accounts = am.getAccountsByType("com.mycustomtype");
if(accounts.length >= 1) {
    accountExists = true;
}
```

Comment: apart from com.cutomtype.. we use "com.google" will it give all the accounts added in the device ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get this from `accounts.length`

```
if (accounts.length > 0) {
    // Account found
} else {
    // No account found
}
```

Comment: This gave me an error "Cannot invoke size() on the array type Account[]. I was able to get it working using accounts.length >= 1 instead though.